# 301 redirect in htacess for a completly new website

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I have a completely new website that replaced the old website (the original was an old Joomla website and the new one is Wordpress). The websites don't have the same structure, so I need that all traffic form the old website to be redirected to the homepage of the new website.

Someone told me this is the easiest way, and I need to do it in .htacess file (the host is an Appache machine, with Cpanel acess).

With cache activated, the old website has some pattern like: www.website.com/index.php/en/folder_name/file.html 
So I think I need to forward all /index.php/en/* to www.website.com ... but I didn't find any similar solution on the questions archive.
Since I'm not familiar with .htacess commands is there an easy commands for this?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need is a `RewriteRule` (and to turn on the `RewriteEngine`)

Here, I'm editing the already-present WordPress `.htaccess` file:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# The new rule, make it first, top priority
RewriteRule ^index\.php/en/ / [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

This should redirect all `index.php/en/` requests to the main site. (Now tested on my own server.)

Do note that Apache2 needs to have `AllowOverride` and `mod_rewrite` enabled, but since you've mentioned other redirects already happening, you should be good to go.

Comment: Thank you! Unfortunately it does not seem to work as expected: if I write www.website.com/index.php/en/contact.html  it redirects to www.website.com/en/contact.html

Comment: I've edited it to use an absolute URL, you can try that instead - hope it helps!

Comment: Thank you again, but unfortunately still not working. Maybe is some stuff that Wordpress core redirects? (or some caching? - but I deactivated all caching from core+cpanel cache settings).   Or can be something from other htacess rules?

Comment: WordPress does do some redirecting, from memory - also, web browsers aggressively cache the 301 (especially Firefox). Unfortunately I can't take a more thorough look at it right now, as I'm on mobile, but I can take another look later on when I'm back at my computer.

Comment: @ioanis I had the Regex slightly wrong, and I've now accounted for WordPress, please see the updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

In your oldsite/.htaccess, add this Redirect

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/index\.php/en/.*$ http://newsite.com/
```

This will redirect all requests of **oldsite.com/index.php/en/** to the hompage of **newsite.com** .

Comment: Thank you for response! Sorry, I think I didn't explain my problem werry well :(    I kept the domain, I only changed the website with a new, modern version, and for simplicity I changed the CMS.   But the domain is the same.